# Task Manager with Trac support for Mac

Tags: eclipse, trac, macos, mylyn

Found Mylyn as a very good task manager that supports Trac and Gmail Task.

I've seen Tasktop, but looking for something with smaller memory footprint that I could always run in background.

Is there any lighter client (not on Eclipse platform) to manager at least Trac tasks (via XML-RPC) and in best case scenario with GMail Tasks support?

Answer (score 0):

i'd like to clarify, for what reasons does a web browser showing Trac running in the background not qualify? for some reason i cannot write this as a comment for the question.

Comment: Offline access is usually the reason I go looking for something like this. It can be very useful if you travel a lot, even with the widely available WiFi access these days.

Comment: right, there is no mention of offline requirement in OP, so i didn't consider that. either way, i'm not aware of any lighter offline client than Mylyn.

Comment: Task management tool works very well when it does not take much time for tracking tasks itself. After trying plugin in Eclipse, I realised, that it is much easier to use it instead of opening several pages in browser.

Rather than opening Trac page, I would prefer to have some widget on  MacOS dashboard or even integrated in iGoogle or just very small application that is always running. I think, the main requirements would be very simple interface like Google Tasks in GMail. The main disadvantage of Google Tasks that you can not assign them to several people.

Answer (score 0):

currently tasktop and mylyn both require eclipse, there was talk about porting stuff over to netbeans. Netbeans is coded java but does use less memory than eclipse. Eclipse does use a lot of ram but the app is always very responsive and never really feels like a java app.

If you use bugzilla, there are standalone clients for bugzilla.